# Does .dll ignore import errors, clr

Tags: c#, dll, reference, using

I got a question for you guys who are a little more knowledgeable about *c#* and the *using* keyword.

Say I got the following classes:

> using Project.BuildB.B
>
> namespace Project.BuildA
>
> public class A
> {
> }

and

> namespace Project.BuildB
>
> public class B
> {
> }

Now say that I replaced the *BuildA.dll* on a computer without adding the *BuildB.dll*, wouldn't that cause an error if they run the .exe?

I have done the above, by mistake, however I haven't gotten any complaints from the people I gave the patch to about any error messages. I am just wondering if *c#* or *.net* handles it because the code is just trying to make contact with the *.dll* and not trying to use it in the code. The thing I am most worried about is if this can have any underlying consequences, like unpredictable executioning.

I have tried to look for answers on this topic, but I find mostly questions about trying to fins missing *.dll*'s. Thanks to anyone who got an answer for this.

Comment: Hello, could you please add a better description for question? Are asking about how CLR works or you need to know how to make possible to not add referenced dlls in your solution execution folder?

Comment: *without adding the BuildB.dll* means that the BuildB is completely missing or is just not replaced with the newer version?

Comment: @WiktorZychla It was never added with the newest build. So the computer has the *BuildA.dll*, in which class A is *using Project.Build.B* but the *BuildB.dll* was never added to the computer. In my mind it should throw an error or something to show that the program can't find *BuildB.dll*. The people I sent it to are older generation, and also had a coder with them, but I have not heard any mention of any errors showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. It seems that due to differenet version of Windows can bypass this. I used Windows 11 and compiled it to x86 while the workstation uses Windows 7 x64. It all worked, aka showed errors, when I went to my PC with Windows XP and compiled it there.